# Density functions with ellipsoidal symmetry

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I'm currently working on Hidden Markov models. I know that we must first train the 
observation sequence to obtain the model parameters such as the initial and transition probability. And this is done using the Baum-Welch (L.E Baum et al , 1970). The hidden states are continuous multivariate probability density functions which are assumed to have ellipsoid symmetry. But this algorithm encounters difficulties when the densities of the states are not log-concave.(Liporace, 1982).

Please help me in understanding the relationship between the density which is non-log concave and the density which has an ellipsoid symmetry.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elliptical distributions have densities whose level sets are ellipses/ellipsoids and so on. They can be light tailed (like a multivariate normal, say) or heavy tailed (like a multivariate Cauchy, say). Elliptical distributions are a pretty broad class.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution

Log-concave distributions are such that the log of the density is concave. With elliptical distributions, the ones with heavier-than-exponential tails won't be log-concave, for example. So the multivariate log-t isn't log-concave except in the limit as the d.f. go to infinity (i.e. to the normal)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function#Log-concave_distributions (examples)

http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~gwalther/logconcave.pdf  (discussion and some theory)